# Get values based on IF condition

Tags: mysql, sql

**[SQL-Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d81389/5)**

```
CREATE TABLE Campaigns (
    Campaign_ID VARCHAR(255),
    Campaign_Type VARCHAR(255),
    Quantity_Offered VARCHAR(255),
    Quantity_Sold VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO Campaigns
(Campaign_ID, Campaign_Type, Quantity_Offered, Quantity_Sold)
VALUES 
("C001", "Type_A", "500", "300"),
("C002", "Type_B", "600", "400"),
("C003", "Type_B", "900", "400"),
("C004", "Type_B", "930", "800"),
("C005", "Type_A", "150", "120"),
("C006", "Type_A", "430", "400"),
("C007", "Type_B", "850", "550"),
("C008", "Type_A", "730", "650"),
("C009", "Type_A", "580", "370");
```

In the table above I have different campaigns with different `Campaign_Type`.

Now, I want to use a query which selects the `Quantity` based on the `Campaign_Type`:
If the `Campaign_Type` is `Type_A` the `Quantity_Sold` should be used. 
If the `Campaign_Type` is `Type_B` the `Quantity_Offered` should be used.

I think the query should look something like this:

```
SELECT
Campaign_ID,
Campaign_Type,
If Campaign_Type ="Type_A" Then Quantity_Sold else Quantity_Offered AS Quantity
FROM Campaigns;
```

However, I could not make it work so far. 
What do I need to change to make the `IF` condition work?

Comment: Seems like you want a `case` _expression_.

Comment: use case for this

Comment: I.e. `case when Campaign_Type ="Type_A" Then Quantity_Sold else Quantity_Offered end AS Quantity`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use case like this

```
SELECT
Campaign_ID, Campaign_Type, 
case when Campaign_Type ="Type_A" 
then Quantity_Sold 
else Quantity_Offered 
end as Quantity 
FROM Campaigns
```

for single case [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d81389/10)

for multiple cases [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/719323/2)

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I needed. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d81389/10

Comment: Just for my own documentation. Here is a fiddle which uses mutliple conditions: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/719323/2

Answer (score 1):

You used the [IF statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/if.html), but that's for executing different operation upon a condition.
Since in your use case you need to return a different value/colum you need to use the [IF()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) function:

```sql
SELECT
    Campaign_ID,
    Campaign_Type,
    If(Campaign_Type = "Type_A", Quantity_Sold, Quantity_Offered) AS Quantity
FROM
    Campaigns;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below query

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d81389/12)

```
SELECT campaign_id, 
       campaign_type, 
       CASE 
         WHEN campaign_type = "Type_A" THEN quantity_sold 
         WHEN campaign_type = "Type_B" THEN quantity_offered 
       END Quantity 
FROM   campaigns
```